# How to pass object type variable into helm_release resource in terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am running out of ideas of how can I set object type var as helm variable in terraform. I want to set the following variable and pass it to helm chart:

```
resource "helm_release" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
  chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
  version    = "9.9.2"

  set {
    name  = "extraArgs"
    value = {balance-similar-node-groups:true,skip-nodes-with-system-pods:false}
  }
```

I get an error that value can be string only, but chart expects object type. Anyone smart knows how to solve this?

link to helm chart docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/charts/cluster-autoscaler

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `set` blocks, as SamRoch08 [indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997646/3289080), but you don't need to use dynamic blocks to take advantage of that. In fact, it's as simple as:

```
resource "helm_release" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
  chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
  version    = "9.9.2"

  set {
    name  = "extraArgs.balance-similar-node-groups"
    value = true
  }
  set {
    name  = "extraArgs.skip-nodes-with-system-pods"
    value = false
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dynamic blocks. According to the doc, "set" is repeatable for each extra argument you need.

```
    variable "helm_extra_args" {
      type = map(string)
      default = {
        "balance-similar-node-groups" = "true",
        "skip-nodes-with-system-pods" = "false"
      }
    }

    resource "helm_release" "cluster_autoscaler" {
      name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
      chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"
      repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
      version    = "9.9.2"

      dynamic "set" {
        for_each = var.helm_extra_args
        content {
          name  = set.key 
          value = set.value 
        }
      }
    }
```

Add elements to your map variable to dynamically add arguments to your resource.